# Automatic coloring of Hashtags in Edittext while typing in Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, highlight

So I have an "EditText" in my Layout for simple Textinput.
When I write a hashtag, for example "#hello", I want that hashtag to get highlighted in blue

```
editText.setOnTextChangedListener(...) {
   public void afterTextChanged(...)
        // replace current String with editText.setText(Html.parse(...));
}
```

I've already tried some ways to achieve that - SpannableStrings and HTML-based setTexts in my afterTextChangedListener - the only problem I got here was, my cursor jumped to the first position when I tried to type something - so a real-time highlighting doesn't work like that in Android Java I guess - not with my algorithm, at least.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If the cursor jumping to first position is your real problem then that can be solved by this `editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());` . Use this code after you have done the color change.

Comment: @sunilsunny the problem here is, that I wont be able to type text in the middle of the text - so that wouldn't work me

Answer (score 0):

As you already know how to color i will just suggest how you could do the trick changing the String keeping the cursor at position using the method that sunil sunny suggested.

```
editText.setOnTextChangedListener(...) {
   public void afterTextChanged(...)
        int currentSelectionStart = editText.getSelectionStart()
        int currentSelectionEnd = editText.getSelectionEnd()
        // replace current String with Spannable for every "Hashtag"
        editText.setSelection(currentCursorPosition,currentSelectionEnd )
}
```